# Google Analytics Report Integration with java application

Tags: spring-boot, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have a java application where users with different roles logged in and perform various activities. I am tracking each user with their useid and Roles and creating custom reports in Google analytics through GTM. In reports i am displaying which user with what roles logged in how many times which date visited etc.I GA i created custom reports which gives charts and table.Charts which GA is giving is as below.

[image]

In my java spring application in admin section i want to display the above graph. Please suggest me the steps and action i need to follow to integrate GA reports graph to my java application.

Regards,
Prabhash Mishra

Answer (score 0):

GA4 has a [reporting API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1) You can use that to pull the data. It may be quite uncomfortable to pull the data via it, so there's another option. You can seamlessly [export your data to BQ](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9358801?hl=en) then ETL it from there using some public libraries for working with BQ.

Going the BQ route will result in way easier debugging since you'd see how the data really looks like directly in BQ.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I want to display the charts mention in question in iFrame of our application. Can you give me an idea what i need to do for that.

Comment: Can i user Embed API to achieve it.

Comment: No, you can't. To my knowledge, analytics graphs are not as easily sharable as youtube videos. They're just not meant to be shared with public like that. Data is power, you don't just give it away to random strangers, unless you really want to work on sanitizing it, and still it will be a lot of work for almost nonsensical benefit.  A good reason for doing so can be when your clients want to measure their traffic on your site. That is solved by letting them install their GTM snippets alongside yours.